# Массив $_POST не заполняется

Tags: javascript, php, docker

С помощью JS выполняю запрос к файлу redirect.php

```
addTaskButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
    console.log('addTask button clicked');
    postData('redirect.php', {'res': 'addTask'}).then((data) => {
        console.log(data.res);
    })
})
```

Сама функция postData

```
//// Определяем функцию которая принимает в качестве параметров url и данные которые необходимо обработать
const postData = async (url = '', data = {}) => {
    // Формируем запрос
    const response = await fetch(url, {
        // По умолчанию метод GET
        method: 'POST',
        // Заголовок
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(data)
    });
    return await response.json();
}
```

Файл redirect.php.

```
<?php
$res = $_POST;
//$res = json_encode($res);
var_dump($res);
?>
```

Для начала хочу хотя бы вернуть массив $_POST, но он пустой.
[image: Запрос]
[image: Ответ]
Все работает на Docker

Comment: content type => `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`

Comment: Спасибо большое, помогло!

Answer (score 0):

На основании комментария InDevX, функцию postData переделал так:

```
//// Определяем функцию которая принимает в качестве параметров url и данные которые необходимо обработать
const postData = async (url = '', data = {}) => {
    // Формируем запрос
    const response = await fetch(url, {
        // По умолчанию метод GET
        method: 'POST',
        // Заголовок
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(data)
    });
    return await response.json();
}
```

Заработало, массив $_POST заполнился